# micrpython machine library i2c write functions do not seem to work at all--any idea why?

Tags: python, i2c, micropython

I am currently working on a simple project in micropython, using a BMP388 barometric pressure sensor (datasheet here: https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/BST-BMP388-DS001-01.pdf). I am having trouble with Micropython's writeto_mem() and writeto() functions (documentation: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html). I do not understand why these functions appear unable to write to my registers, while the readfrom_mem() function works just fine.

Here are code snippets I've tried:

```
from machine import I2C
from time import sleep

_address = 0x76 #or 0x77 if I disconnect a certain pin, but this is not an issue.
i2c = I2C(scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21))

def set_sampling_v1():
    i2c.writeto(_address, bytes(0x1c), False)
    i2c.writeto(_address, bytes(0x0d), True)
    #I also tried i2c.writeto(_address, bytes(0x1c0d), True)
    print(i2c.readfrom_mem(_address, 0x1c, 1))  #get what I just wrote
    print(i2c.readfrom_mem(_address, 0x00, 1))  #get device ID, confirm we're able to read

def set_sampling_v2():
    i2c.writeto_mem(_address, 0x1C, bytes(0x0D))
    print(i2c.readfrom_mem(_address, 0x1c, 1))  #get what I just wrote
    print(i2c.readfrom_mem(_address, 0x00, 1))  #get device ID, confirm we're able to read

set_sampling_v1()
#Or try:
#set_sampling_v2()
```

In both set_sampling functions, the readfrom_mem() functions return:

```
x00
b'P'  #which is just x50, and is the correct value.
```

In the case of v1, I am unsure how exactly micropython handles writeto(), but the I2C protocol takes the device address, a "RW" bit, and then a pair of bytes, before a stop condition, with the RW bit set to 0 for "write". So I tried both attempts at writing which made sense to try. In v2, since it is using the "convenience" function, I assume writeto_mem() replicates what I tried to do in the first version. I also assume micropython is able to supply the correct RW bit value when supplied with an address. Presumably it's doing something like (_address | 0x01) in the underlying function.

To summarize i2c operation, the BMP388 takes the device's address and a RW bit set to tell it whether to read or write. Then it takes a pair of bytes, one specifying the register and one specifying the data to be written. A stop condition follows at the end, to tell it that communication is complete. This is also why I've tried writing 0x1c0d as well as trying two separate write commands, since I was concerned the writeto() function would send the address register once per function call instead of just once. The writeto_mem() function supposedly just needs the device address, target register, and byte to be written, and so I didn't both testing alternative approaches. It's also worth noting, in version 1 of the sample function, the line

```
i2c.writeto(_address, 0x1c0d, True)
```

has the same x00 and b'p' result when I call the readfrom_mem() function.

Since the read functions return the correct device ID, I trust that x00 is what's actually in the  the 0x1c register (which is where you set the sensor's oversampling rate for pressure and temperature). I've also successfully used the readfrom_mem() function on other registers to read and confirm their default values. Taken together, this convinces me that the function is reading the value in 0x1c and returning x00 because the writeto functions are failing to write.

Any insight into this would be welcome. I am about to review the datasheet to ensure there isn't something that must be set in a different register before I'm able to alter the contents of read/write registers, but I don't recall seeing such a thing before, and I'm wondering if anyone has insight into this problem.

If you need additional information I haven't provided, please let me know, and I will attempt to update this post as promptly as I can.

Comment: `bytes(0x1c)` returns a [zero-filled bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#bytearray) of length 28. If you want a single byte containing 0x1c, you just need `b'\x1c'`.

Comment: Brilliant! That would account for the problem. Thank you so much.